# How do I make a 2D array in C, with negative lower bounds and positive upper bounds?

Tags: arrays, c, 2d

In Visual Basic I can do something like
`dim MyArray(-10 to 10, -10 to 10) as long`

I was hoping to likewise do this in C with code like
`long MyArray[-10 to 10][-10 to 10];`

However C gives me compiling errors for the above mentioned code. Are negative array indexes not permitted in C? I need this for a 2D intensity plot of values, where the intensity is a function of x and y, where x and y extend into both positive and negative values.

Comment: How many elements are there in the range `-10` to `10` (inclusive the ends)? Create an array of that number of elements, and shift the indexes so `-10` becomes `0`, `-9` becomes `1`, etc. You can hide it using a structure and a set of generic function if you want.

Answer (score 3):

Building upon William's answer, you can define a 2D array of `long` and use a pointer to implement your idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    long my2DArray[21][21];
    // simulate dim myArray[-10 to 10][-10 to 10] as long
    long (*myArray)[21] = (long(*)[21])&my2DArray[10][10];

    for (int i = -10; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (int j = -10; j <= 10; j++) {
            myArray[i][j] = i * j;
        }
    }
    for (int i = -10; i <= 10; i++) {
        for (int j = -10; j <= 10; j++) {
            printf(" %4d", myArray[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
  100   90   80   70   60   50   40   30   20   10    0  -10  -20  -30  -40  -50  -60  -70  -80  -90 -100
   90   81   72   63   54   45   36   27   18    9    0   -9  -18  -27  -36  -45  -54  -63  -72  -81  -90
   80   72   64   56   48   40   32   24   16    8    0   -8  -16  -24  -32  -40  -48  -56  -64  -72  -80
   70   63   56   49   42   35   28   21   14    7    0   -7  -14  -21  -28  -35  -42  -49  -56  -63  -70
   60   54   48   42   36   30   24   18   12    6    0   -6  -12  -18  -24  -30  -36  -42  -48  -54  -60
   50   45   40   35   30   25   20   15   10    5    0   -5  -10  -15  -20  -25  -30  -35  -40  -45  -50
   40   36   32   28   24   20   16   12    8    4    0   -4   -8  -12  -16  -20  -24  -28  -32  -36  -40
   30   27   24   21   18   15   12    9    6    3    0   -3   -6   -9  -12  -15  -18  -21  -24  -27  -30
   20   18   16   14   12   10    8    6    4    2    0   -2   -4   -6   -8  -10  -12  -14  -16  -18  -20
   10    9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2    1    0   -1   -2   -3   -4   -5   -6   -7   -8   -9  -10
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  -10   -9   -8   -7   -6   -5   -4   -3   -2   -1    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
  -20  -18  -16  -14  -12  -10   -8   -6   -4   -2    0    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18   20
  -30  -27  -24  -21  -18  -15  -12   -9   -6   -3    0    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27   30
  -40  -36  -32  -28  -24  -20  -16  -12   -8   -4    0    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40
  -50  -45  -40  -35  -30  -25  -20  -15  -10   -5    0    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45   50
  -60  -54  -48  -42  -36  -30  -24  -18  -12   -6    0    6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54   60
  -70  -63  -56  -49  -42  -35  -28  -21  -14   -7    0    7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63   70
  -80  -72  -64  -56  -48  -40  -32  -24  -16   -8    0    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80
  -90  -81  -72  -63  -54  -45  -36  -27  -18   -9    0    9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81   90
 -100  -90  -80  -70  -60  -50  -40  -30  -20  -10    0   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90  100
```

Comment: I had a working answer but couldn't make it simple without a typedef for each row such as `typedef long myArrType[21];`  – frowned on :) and it still needed a cast to assign the mid-pointer.

Comment: I'd expect it to work in practice, but doesn't this solution technically result in undefined behavior? `myArray` points to the middle of an array object (a row of `my2dArray`) but is used to form addresses beyond 1-past the end of the array object, violating [§6.5.6 ¶8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p8) in the way described in [Annex J.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2): _"An array subscript is out of range, even if an object is apparently accessible with the given subscript (as in the lvalue expression a[1][7] given the declaration int a[4][5]) (6.5.6)."_

Comment: @adabsurdum: yes, technically the behavior is undefined, yet I don't expect any compiler to generate code that would not behave as expected... But life is full of surprises :)

Answer (score 2):

Negative index on arrays are definitely possible in C, after all it's just an arithmetic operation. If you really need to use negative indexes, you can use a pointer that points to the middle value and then use negative index on that one.

As a quick example:

```
long myArray[21] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21};
long *myArrayPtr = &myArray[10];

printf("%ld\n", myArrayPtr[-10]); // outputs 1
printf("%ld\n", myArrayPtr[0]);   // outputs 11
printf("%ld\n", myArrayPtr[10]);  // outputs 21
```

Comment: Can this be extended to a 2D array as in the question?

Comment: @WeatherVane: yes it can, but it seems to require a cast.